# Activeadmin Rails 7 Tailwind Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-7

Just install active_admin in rails 7 and ruby 3.1.0

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin', branch: 'master'
```

It add two style files. One is active_admin_old.scss
and other is active_admin.css which a code like it

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Now when i run server I get UI like it

[image]

If i rename active_admin_old.scss to active_admin.scsss then UI is like that

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: How do you run the dev server? You have to make sure to run the tailwind process too!

If you run `/bin/dev`, it starts the `Procfile.dev` that should have the rails server process and the tailwind process

Comment: yes i do /bin/dev

Comment: Have you run `rails assets:precompile`? Is the import on the `application.html.erb`correct?

Comment: no i am using esbuild

Answer (score 0):

It is already published activeadmin 3.1.0 in rubygems. This version is compatible with rails 7 and it seems css is working correctly, this version does not provide the tailwind css version.

In your special case I would change in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin', branch: 'master'
```

by

```
gem 'activeadmin'
```

And execute `bundle update`

On a clean installation I would [follow common steps](https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html) adding typical gems to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'draper'
gem 'pundit'
```

And run `bundle install`